# iOS 10 Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0xdead10cc

Tags: ios10, crash-reports

I'm suddenly seeing hundreds of crashes on an otherwise stable app after people upgraded to iOS 10. Mostly, all of them are to do with:

```
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0xdead10cc
```

A lot of the crash logs don't have much symbolicated, except they seem to have something in common (I think) - they're crashing in the background when the app is trying to sync / access the database or doing something else with the sqlite database (such as writing to it). This was working just fine before, but suddenly people are reporting their iPhones are rebooting while using the app.

Anyone else having similar issues? Any resolution? The crashlogs aren't helping much as the crash is somewhere within sqlite3.c while trying either on a `sqlite3_step` or `open`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry but I started a posted a separate question since I discovered it wasn't anything to do with SQLite. It was in fact the new `UNUserNotificationCenter`. Explained more in detail here:

[Springboard crashing when adding a lot of triggers to UNUserNotificationCenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40630504/springboard-crashing-when-adding-a-lot-of-triggers-to-unusernotificationcenter)