# IOS App Crash on Lauch

Tags: ios, swift

My app is working fine at all, but recently an user told me his app is closing after its launch. He was very nice and accepted to join my external testers on TestFlight so I can get his error. Well that's my problem. He installed TestFlight, got the same error, but I still get no log errors, even on TestFlight mode. I installed also Fabric - CrashLytics, but it does not show any errors on log also. Someone has an idea of what else can I do?

EDIT: I logged in with his credentials on my iPhone/Simulator and works well. It's something with his device probably.

EDIT2: I got the error message from user's device:

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000100054ee0
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Comment: This likely was already done, and won't ultimately help, but the question you need to be asking now is "What's different?" Things that easily come to mind - iOS version, device version, app dependencies (if any), memory usage (including what this user has running on their app), ??? Personally, I'd start looking at available memory. (I see that you have an answer addressing iOS version and app dependencies. Ok, that one too.) Good luck!

Comment: I asked these things also. He has an iPhone 6, IOS 10.2 and said he has 6GB free.

Comment: Right there I had to up vote. I'm still kind of new here so I don't know if I could somehow bookmark this. (I will in my browser.) I agree, it's probably something with his device. Digging *just* a bit deeper :-) I assume you have no third party dependancies, are using straight-up Apple frameworks, and this is something nobody else is getting launch issues with, right? I have no issues with my app - soon to be doubled - but this is always my concern. "Can I duplicate the issue?" Like I already said, goo luck. If you figure it out, let us all know.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40630504/springboard-crashing-when-adding-a-lot-of-triggers-to-unusernotificationcenter